# How to add and save ACF input values to custom post type on frontend form

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I have a Listing website which has a CPT of Listing. For this, I created an acf field for listings. When I try to edit a created Listing from the backend/admin, the fields show but when I want to add to the already created frontend form for users, it doesn't save.

```
<?php

$settings = [
     "post_id" => "new_post",
      "field_groups" => ["group_63e4f4c177c0d"],
      "fields" => ["field_63159781abd35"],
 "new_post" => [
    "field_63159781abd35" => $_POST["acf"]["field_63159781abd35"],
 ],

  "form" => false,
  "label_placement" => "top",
  "instruction_placement" => "label",
];
acf_form($settings);
?>
```

The input field is created and filled with the placeholder I used to create the field. How can i make sure the data inputted by a user is saved?

Comment: Did you use `acf_form_head`? That is the actual "workhorse" here, it provides the client-side coding necessary to automatically submit your data to the server and get it stored/updated. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/create-a-front-end-form/

Comment: @CBroe Thanks but yes, I added the `acf_form_head` at the beginning of the template. Still doesn't work and the link you sent mostly refers to creating a new form which I don't want to do. I simply want to add the field to the form I already have and save the input to the Listing(cpt) created.

Comment: The example here https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf_form/#create-a-specific-post specifies post_type and post_status within the `new_post` option, yours appears to contain one ACF field only - not sure if that is actually enough to create a new post. Try and add type and status, and see what happens then.

Comment: hi @CBroe it still didn't work for me. I've tried to use the `update_field(field,value,id)` function but I can't get the user-inputted value. 
`
$field_key = "field_63159781abd35";

$value = $_POST['acf[field_63159781abd35]']; /*I haven't been able to get the user input here*/

$value = "Portugal";

update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id );
` 
Here's what I have at the moment to update the field since it's already been created. I justhaven't ben able to get the user input

Comment: That's the thing, you are not supposed to access anything yourself in this scenario - by embedding the `acf_form_head` scripts, everything should happen automatically.

Comment: I have done that now. Instead it returns the “a critical error has occurred on your site” error.

Comment: I thought you said you had that in there the whole time? As for the error, enable WP debug mode, and check what the PHP error log has to say.